# How to get response headers in neo4j - apoc.load.jsonParams()?

Tags: rest, neo4j, neo4j-apoc, response-headers

I have the following CQL apoc query in neo4j that works fine to get response payload from a rest GET request:

```
CALL apoc.load.jsonParams($uri, {Authorization: $Bearertoken}, null)
YIELD value
UNWIND value.items AS item
RETURN item
```

However, the **uri** uses pagenation and the next page **uri** is present in the response header. Therefore, I need a way to retrieve the response header along with the value. Please let me know if there is a way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `apoc.load.jsonParams` procedure does not support returning the response header.

You can write your own code instead. [Here is an article](https://neo4j.com/blog/cypher-load-json-from-url/) that can help get you started.